# ActiveX component can't create object vbscript Win 8.1

Tags: vbscript, activex

I have a vbscript that creates an object, RoAx.FrmInput, as well as other objects.  It' been working for some time and has worked very reliably in Win XP and Win 7 XPMode.  I even think I had it working in Win 8.1, but now it throws the 429 error.

I've checked and the dll is properly registered with the following keys

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{3BDAAC41-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\RoAx.RofrmInput
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\RoAx.RofrmInput\Clsid
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{3BDAAC43-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}\ProgID
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{3BDAAC41-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{3BDAAC43-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}\ProgID
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interface\{3BDAAC41-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}
```

So I ran Dependency Walker and found there were six dependencies of dependencies where the file could not be found.  These files are on my Win 8.1 system, but must not be in the right location.  For example:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL is a dependency of c:\windows\system32\USER32.DLL and is listed as file not found.  I located it in a folder, C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_d032dc3cb14ba8a7
```

The other five missing dlls are also dependencies of windows core dll's and are located in the same folder.

Is there any way of rectifying this?  What I really need is a method that is simple enough to pass along to my users

Comment: dunno why, but the folder where I found the referenced "missing folder" was omitted when I posted the q.  That dll was found in the folder, C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_d032dc3cb14ba8a7

Comment: Let's start with the basics... is it a 32-bit component? If so, and this is a WSH script, are you running the 32-bit version of `cscript/wscript.exe` (in the `SysWow64` folder)? If ASP, does your application pool have "Enable 32-Bit applications" set to true?

Comment: Thx.  As you suspected, it was an architecture problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I was trying to run a plugin for the modeling program, Rhinoceros 5.0. The plugin was compiled in 32 bit Delphi 5, but I was trying to run it in the default, 64 bit, instead.